# java classcastexception during interface and some class casting

Tags: java

I am getting `ClassCastException` while casting between some class say  `MarketplaceBasicProductList` and an interface `IMarketplaceProductList` classes -why ?

```
public static IMarketplaceProductList createMarketplaceBasicProductList(Table basicInfoTable) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        if (basicInfoTable != null) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= basicInfoTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                IMarketplaceBasicProduct product = createMarketplaceBasicProduct(basicInfoTable, i);
                list.add(product);
            }
        }
        return (IMarketplaceProductList) new MarketplaceBasicProductList(list);
    }
```

### other details are :

1.

```
 public interface IMarketplaceProductList extends Serializable {

    public int getProductCount();
    public IMarketplaceBasicProduct getProductMKPInfo(int index);

}
```

1. `public class MarketplaceBasicProductList extends AbstractProductList` {  ..............
2. `public abstract class AbstractProductList implements IProductList` {  .............

do i need to add also implements IMarketplaceProductList here ?

1. `public interface IMarketplaceBasicProduct extends Serializable` { ...get methods for MarketplaceBasicProduct functions..

5.`public class MarketplaceBasicProduct extends BasicProduct  implements IMarketplaceBasicProduct, IGenericProductFields {`

1. `public class BasicProduct extends AbstractProduct {`

7.`public abstract class AbstractProduct extends AbstractGenericProduct implements IProduct {`

do i need to add also implements `IMarketplaceBasicProduct` here ?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `ClassCastException` since your class `MarketplaceBasicProductList` **is not** `IMarketplaceProductList`.

```
MarketplaceBasicProductList extends AbstractProductList implements IMarketplaceProductList
```

Looking from the structure that you have, `AbstractProductList` will be generic for every type of Product list and `IMarketplaceProductList` will be containing specific methods for `MarketplaceBasicProductList`, so only `MarketplaceBasicProductList` will implement `IMarketplaceProductList`

Also I feel `IMarketplaceProductList` will be providing features on and above `IProductList` so it `IMarketplaceProductList` definition should be like:

```
public interface IMarketplaceProductList extends IProductList {

}
```